# Flutter iOS build fail - Snapshotting (IOSArch.armv7) exited with non-zero exit code: -4

Tags: xcode, flutter

Trying to build a iOS project fail. This is the error code:

```
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...          
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -4

Building App.framework for arm64...
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             35.3s
Built to build/aot/.
Snapshotting (IOSArch.armv7) exited with non-zero exit code: -4
Snapshotting (IOSArch.arm64) exited with non-zero exit code: 0
cp: build/aot/App.framework: No such file or directory
error: cannot parse the debug map for 'build/aot/App.framework/App': No such
file or directory
Failed to generate debug symbols (dSYM) file for
build/aot/App.framework/App.
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build
description
```

Flutter (Channel master, v1.8.2-pre.131, on Mac OS X 10.13.6)

Tested with Xcode 10.1 and 9.4.1 with the same result.

Temp workaround just disable 32bit architectures:

Remove armv7 and arm7s under Build Settings - Valid Architectures.
This removes support for 32 bit devices like iPhone 5c.